# good and extensive book(tutorial) on data structures

Tags: c, data-structures

I have been searching from a week may be for a book or tutorial with extensive data structures material in C ,but I could not find.I want to cover linked list,binary trees,hash tables,graphs etc...I want it in C, because I don`t want to mess with OOP and I don't want to read for linked lists in language without pointers.Some links will be appreciated.

Comment: [Classic Data Structures by D.Samanta](http://www.amazon.in/Classic-Data-Structures-Samanta-Debasis/dp/812033731X).

Answer (score 3):

As a beginner you can start with [Classic Data Structures by D.Samanta](http://www.amazon.in/Classic-Data-Structures-Samanta-Debasis/dp/812033731X). This is a good book on data structures. But keep in mind that it includes no codes but only pseudo codes and after reading the pseudo codes you will be able to implement it in C language easily.

After that I would suggest you [Introduction to Algorithms, Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937) by Thomas H. Cormen, one of the best book on datastructures and algorithm.

For online tutorials: [MIT Open Course Ware](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/).

Comment: Your welcome. I glad that it helped :). Once I also had this issue. I asked my colleagues and searched on internet but I did't get the right answer. once I was in my faculty library where I saw this book , I started to read and found that it is easy and good for beginners like me :).

Answer (score 1):

If you're really ambitious and want to find the best quality data structers to learn, go find *The Art of Computer Programming* by Donald Knuth. Particularly volume 1 and volume 3.

Comment: The assembly language is stopping me I guess plus all the math in them.May be someday when I retire and have time I will read them.

Comment: @user3137477 He does use assembly language, but all of his algorithms are first described in pseudocode, then described with a flow chart, and only after that does he implement it in assembly. Plus, having read them myself I can safely say that you can skip over all of the math and still have a strong understanding of the concepts he gives (at least for data structures).

Comment: But it has 4 volumes (about of 3000 pages) which is painful to read :)

Comment: "Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs" by N. Wirth is more brief and uses Pascal instead of assembly.

Answer (score 1):

"algorithm in c" robert sedgewick It could be a good start as you've not already studied them and then can study Cormen.It's good if you follow a book rather than tutorials on Internet.